# Is there a Excel Formula for auto filling a price when certain option of choices is picked?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working in Excel. I am trying to come up with a formula that is linked to a drop down menu of choices. I have attached an image below that shows a 'Status' column and 'Double Handling' column. My end goal is when you click a status option the corresponding price gets autofilled in the double handling column.

**For example** **Status :Price**

Unchecked :$400,

Checked :$600,

Laydown :$200,

in SWO :$200,

Progress :$200,

Paint :$200,

Laydown :$200,

Site :$200,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it may seem a bit lenghty, if for whatever reason you want to change up amount, I believe you could nicely implement `CHOOSE` here:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(A1,{"Unchecked Drawing","Checked Drawing","in SWO","Progress Assign LamSar Shop","Progress Assign Subcontractor","Paint","Laydown","Site"},0),400,600,200,200,200,200,200,200)
```

Range `A1` in my formula refers to the cell with the drop-down. Also, when empty, there will be an error (since `MATCH` cannot find a match). You could counter that with wrapping the formula in an `IFERROR(.....,"")`.

Comment: awesome!! works perfect, thank you so much. Taught me something new :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have your Drop Down options on another tab (a Lookup Sheet), then you can put the Price next to them, and use a `VLOOKUP`

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,LookupSheet!$A:$B, 2, FALSE)
```

This also lets you use a Named Range in your Drop-Downs, so that you just have to add or remove items to the Lookup Sheet, and it will automatically update all of your options.  The Named Range would need to contain a Function that used `INDEX` to set the range, like this:

```
=LookupSheet!$A$1:INDEX(LookupSheet!$A:$A, MAX(COUNTA(LookupSheet!$A:$A), 1))
```

(If your Lookup Sheet includes a Header Row, then you will probably want to change `$A$1` to `$A$2`, and that final `, 1))` to `, 2))` instead)

---

If you don't want to use a Lookup Sheet, you can include the Lookup Table in the function as an array:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, {"Unchecked",400;"Checked",600;"Laydown",200;"in SWO",200;"Progress",200;"Paint",200;"Laydown",200;"Site",200}, 2, FALSE)
```

The whole array goes inside braces (curly brackets, `{}`), values on the same Row are separated with Commas (`{Input,Output}`), and Rows are separated with Semicolons (`{Input1,Output1;Input2,Output2}`)

Comment: I like your (last) answer, basically building your own table. ++

Comment: @JvdV It's very similar to your `CHOOSE` method (you appear to have typed a lot faster than I did xD), but I find it easier to visually match the Categories and Fees like this.  But, `CHOOSE` is a much-overlooked and very useful function, so it's nice to see someone else still employs it :)